# Adding buttons to toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to add a transparent toolbar and add 4 buttons with images on it. How can i do this by code?

My workings so far;

i have added the toolbar and made it transparent
and now i am trying to add 4 buttons with images. How can i do this ? (These 4 buttons should also have a `action` method so when a person clicks on it an action should fire up)

```
toolBar1 = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320 , 320 , 60)];

[toolBar1 setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

[toolBar1 setTranslucent:YES];

NSMutableArray* allthebuttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonWithImage = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] ...... // Now what ??

[self.view addSubview:toolBar1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *myButton1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"email.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toolbarButtonPressed1:)];
[buttonsArray addObject:myButton1];
UIBarButtonItem *myButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button 2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toolbarButtonPressed2:)];  
[buttonsArray addObject:myButton2];
[self setToolbarItems:buttonsArray animated:YES];
```

Note, for the above you'll want to use the toolbar on the navigation view controller.

Comment: Ok, but where are the images in the button ? i need to add images too. and i don't want the title i only want the images to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action];

UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action];

NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: item1, item2, nil];
[toolBar setItems: buttons animated:NO];

[item1 release];
[item2 release];
```

Just make above code for 4 buttons

update 1 :

use following code to get images in buttons

```
UIImageView *btn1Img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1Img"]];

UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn1Img];
```

Comment: Ok, but where are the images in the button ? i need to add images too. and i don't want the title i only want the images to be displayed

Comment: I did upvote, but @ade made the code change first :S Anyway Thank you loads :*

Comment: Don't worry i will be posting more questions soon. make sure you answer it first  :D